# Looping through a json object in recursive function

Tags: javascript, json, recursion

I want to write a recursive function to iterate through a json object using javascript.

I have a sample json file:

```
    {
  "week": [
    [
      {
        "id": "121",
        "amount": 50,
        "numberOfDays": 7,
        "data": {
          "supply": "xyz",
          "price": 50,
        }
      }
    ],
    [
{
        "id": "122",
        "amount": 30,
        "numberOfDays": 6,
        "data": {
          "supply": "xyz",
          "price": 30,
        }
      }
    ],
  ] 
}
```

I want to take each element of the json object array and pass it to a function.

To extract the array elements I am using this code:

```
 for(var i=0;i<array[plan].length; i++){
      var confPlan = array[plan][i];
      console.log(plan);
    }

var Bill = function (plan) {
  return func(plan)
  .then((status) => {
    if(status == '1') {
      // do something
    } else if(status == '0') {
      Bill(plan) // but with the next element of the array from the json file
    }
    })
}
```

please Help!

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what does `func` do? Does it definitely do some async operation?

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: 1. The first three lines do nothing but log each element. 2. What is `func(plan)`? Are you sure it returns a Promise? 3. `bill(plan)` will return `undefined` because you called it Bill, not bill.

Comment: func(plan) is another function which takes the plan as input value and returns the status 0 or 1.

Comment: Don't describe what `func` (why call a function `func`?) does. Add it to your code. If it returns 0 or 1, then it's wrong, because it should return a Promise, because you're calling `.then()` after it. Also, why call `Bill` that calls `func` ? Why not call `func` directly?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your question boils down to wanting to be able to synchronously chain calls to an asynchronous function. I am assuming `func` is an asynchronous function since your using a `.then`, so I simulated it with a timeout. Below is one way to achieve the desired behavior recursively:

```js
data = {
  "week": [
    [{
      "id": "121",
      "amount": 50,
      "numberOfDays": 7,
      "data": {
        "supply": "xyz",
        "price": 50,
      }
    }],
    [{
      "id": "122",
      "amount": 30,
      "numberOfDays": 6,
      "data": {
        "supply": "xyz",
        "price": 30,
      }
    }],
  ]
};

function func(data) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(data);
      resolve(0);
    }, 1000)
  })
}


function loop(data, i = 0) {
  if (i < data.length) {
    func(data[i])
      .then((status) => {
        if (status) {
          // do something
        } else {
          return loop.call(null, data, i += 1)
        }
      })
  }
}

loop(data['week']);
```

The ideal solution involves using `async/await` iteratively in a `for` loop. Not only will it avoid recursion but the structure of the code is cleaner and more familiar. However, I will leave this to you to research.